# using msbuild in a Jenkins multi branch project

Tags: jenkins, asp.net-core, msbuild, devops, multibranch-pipeline

How can I use `MSBuild` in a Jenkins multi-branch project?
Here's my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
     stage('restore') {
        steps {
            sh "echo 'TODO RUN TEST'"
        }
     }
     stage('build') {
        steps {
            bat "\"${tool 'MSBuild'}\" .\\src\\MySollutionName.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=\"Any CPU\" /p:ProductVersion=1.0.0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
        }
     }
     stage('test') {
        steps {
            sh "echo 'TODO RUN TEST'"
        }
     }
   }
}
```

But I'm getting an error message:

> No tool named MSBuild found

Is it possible to use MSBuild in Jenkins multi-branch project?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first tell Jenkins what the MSBuild tool is:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Custom+Tools+Plugin

Have you installed the MSBuild plugin?

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/MSBuild+Plugin

Comment: Still getting `No tool named MsBuild found` with both plugins installed.

Comment: Do you have msbuild installed on the agent?

Comment: yes it is, and it's working fine on conventional build jobs where `msbuild` is being used as part of a 'Execute Windows batch command'

Comment: MSBuild+Plugin does not work with multibranch pipelines for Jenkins 2.263.4. Works only for freestyle projects.